# ICU ustdio.h functions: Undefined symbols on Mac OS when building with CMake

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, linker-errors, icu

I'm making a text-based game, using ICU to process game text from UTF-8-encoded JSON files across the 3 major PC platforms. I'm able to compile and link the game binary with CMake while referencing ICU types such as UChar, UnicodeString, etc. and everything works properly. Bizarrely enough, there are certain headers from which I can't access any types or functions without causing an "Undefined symbols" linker error. Particularly, the header "ustdio.h" from which I need to access u_fopen(), u_fclose(), u_fgets(), etc. to extract unicode strings from my JSON files.

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_u_fclose_57", referenced from:
>      FileReader::Close() in libsource.a(FileReader.cpp.o)
>   "_u_fgets_57", referenced from:
>       FileReader::HasNextLine() in libsource.a(FileReader.cpp.o)
>       FileReader::NextLine() in libsource.a(FileReader.cpp.o)
>   "_u_fopen_57", referenced from:
>       FileReader::FileReader(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >) in libsource.a(FileReader.cpp.o)

I'm using [this CMake module file](https://github.com/julp/FindICU.cmake/blob/master/FindICU.cmake) to locate the `.h` and `.dylib` files. From CMake output, I know it's linking against `/usr/local/lib/libicuuc.dylib`, but looking in that folder I also see plenty of other ICU-related dylibs. Another programmer directed me to check if the symbols I'm looking for are really defined in the `dylib` using `nm` and I can see in the symbol list that they aren't. Am I to assume these symbols are defined in one of the other `dylib` files? If they are, and I find the proper `dylib`, how do I modify `FindICU.cmake` to link against the extra dynamic library? The module seems really obtuse to me and I don't know where I'd change it to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by searching the symbol table of each ICU-related dylib file until I found the missing symbols (which are defined in `libicuio.57.1.dylib`). This helped me realize that the symbols were indeed not being found by FindICU.cmake. I then managed to parse through enough of the file to identify the problem: there's a variable, ICU_FIND_COMPONENTS that must be set to a list of desired components in order for the module file to link against the other dylibs. This variable wasn't documented anywhere, which is pretty frustrating. But I solved the linker error by adding this line to `FindICU.cmake` before line 121:

```
set(${ICU_PUBLIC_VAR_NS}_FIND_COMPONENTS io)
```

Additionally you can check whether a desired component is being linked by outputting the values of variables `ICU_<component>_FOUND`. In my case, `ICU_IO_FOUND` was returning false because the module doesn't search for the io dylib unless explicitly told to do so. This is what clued me into the need to modify `FindICU.cmake` in order to link the extra dylib file where the symbol comes from.

Comment: Use `find_package(ICU COMPONENTS uc io REQUIRED)` instead.